# Is it possible to operate a Tesla coil at lower frequencies?

Tags: frequency, tesla-coil

Tesla coils usually operate at a frequency level between 50 kHz to 1 MHz. What if we use a frequency between 60 to 100 Hz? Will it work? What will be the effect on the spark?

Comment: My old master thesis tutor proposed to make a city-sized 50 Hz tuned tesla coil as air defense. Would solve all seagull problems as well.

Comment: @winny Are you a fan of C&C Red Alert?

Comment: @DKNguyen Of course! We even discussed how to make it aim for the enemy/seagulls like in the game.

Comment: In order to achieve such a low resonant frequency, the inductance and capacitance of the tank circuits would need to be enormous. This would also require them to be physically large, so the main issues you would run into is that it would be extremely expensive and impractical.

Answer (score 2):

A tesla coil (as far as I'm aware) makes significant use of the loosely-coupled, high self-resonant-frequency of the high-voltage secondary winding to produce large voltage magnification and generate the notable arcs seen on the output.

So, if you tried to run a tesla coil at a frequency where secondary-self-resonance is largely impractical then it will barely generate any voltage/arcs at the output.